# Duvida Mysql + PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um sistema de gestão de camepeonatos online (fifa, pes) e estou com um problema, agora estou fazendo a parte onde o usuario vai postar o resultado do jogo, informando o placar e os jogadores que fizeram os gols, pra isso preciso acessar o banco de dados e selecionar a lista de jogadores do clube do usuario e coloca-los em um botão em forma de select pro usuario so clicar, sou iniciante gostaria de saber como faço isso, com qual função, segue exemplo do meu codigo onde consegui pegar os dados do BD

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw", "mith");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$query = "
SELECT C.nome_clube , J.nome_jogador
  FROM clube as C 
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN conta_user as UC ON C.id_clube = UC.id_conta
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN jogador as J ON C.id_clube = J.id_jogador";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["nome_clube"], $row["nome_jogador"]);
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito você quer fazer um campo select em html com os valores do banco, se for isso ficaria assim, onde o value das opções seria o id para você recuperar por post ou javascript e manipular como quiser:

```
<select name="JOGADOR" id="JOGADOR" >
      <?php do { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_jogador']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row['nome_jogador'];?>
        </option>
      <?php  } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Obrigado, desculpa se não fui claro na pergunta sou iniciante ainda meu primeiro projeto, mas obrigado era isso mesmo ;)